# How i Can Move Side Bar to Right on My Account Page

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

I want to Move Side-bar on My Account Page to Right On The Basis Of Admin Configuration Value

After Some Research i found that it can be done by setting Page `layout="2coloums-right"` i saw Lots of Post doing this in

> app/design/...

**EDIT**

here is My

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
</page>
```

how i can do this in my Custom Module

Comment: I don't know why someone give -1 on this, but this question is not that bad. +1 on you question @waqar

Comment: yup @ShoaibMunir i was aslo confused : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to override `customer_account_index.xml`.

To Override this file in your extension, copy `customer_account_index.xml` at `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout` and add below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Account</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

### EDIT :

You can create around plugin for that.

1) create **di.xml** file at `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index">
        <plugin name="MyCucomtLoginAccountLoginPost" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Index" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2) Now, create plugin `VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Index.php` :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer;

class Index
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->setPageLayout('2columns-right');
        return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

Comment: how i can change this Programmatically i actually want to this on the basis of admin congifutration value

Comment: Not sure by configuration. But, You can change by controller.

Comment: how i can change it by controller please let me know

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To override the layout file in module simple

```
SpaceName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layoutname.xml
```

Example

```
SpaceName/ModuleName/view/frontend/cms_index_index.xml
```

Your Case

```
SpaceName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not working for me

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @Qaiser bhai check my updated Question

Comment: use this layout file **Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml**

Comment: okay let me try